# Telegram bot сохранение фотографий

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте, сейчас пишу telegram-bot на c# и возникла следующая проблема: как сохранять картинки у пользователя на устройстве в определенной папке? т.е. есть телеграм бот, который отправляет картинку и нужно, чтобы эта картинка сохранялась в определенном месте.
Спасибо.

Comment: А разве такое вообще возможно? Вы можете отправить файл, а вот как и где сохранять - дело самого пользователя. Почитайте офф. документацию, может и ошибаюсь...

Comment: это невозможно реализовать через бот апи